# Need Query to get start and end timings of continous events

Tags: mysql, sql

i have data like below in the table. i need query to get the start and end time of continous events.

```
ID, Event,  Timestamp
1   Sleep   17-Sep-2021 05:22:01
2   Sleep   17-Sep-2021 05:22:02
3   Sleep   17-Sep-2021 05:22:03
4   Running 17-Sep-2021 05:22:04
5   Running 17-Sep-2021 05:22:05
6   Eating  17-Sep-2021 05:22:06
7   Eating  17-Sep-2021 05:22:07
9   Sleep   17-Sep-2021 05:22:08
10  Sleep   17-Sep-2021 05:22:09
11  Sleep   17-Sep-2021 05:22:10
```

i need output as below.

```
Event      Start Time                  End Time
Sleep      17-Sep-2021 05:22:01        17-Sep-2021 05:22:03
Running    17-Sep-2021 05:22:04        17-Sep-2021 05:22:05
Eating     17-Sep-2021 05:22:06        17-Sep-2021 05:22:07
Sleep      17-Sep-2021 05:22:08        17-Sep-2021 05:22:10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, the difference of row numbers is probably the simplest solution:

```
select event, min(timestamp) as start_time, max(timestamp) as end_time
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by event order by timestamp) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by event, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by min(timestamp);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results from the subquery, you will see how the difference between the two sequence numbers is constant when the event does not change.